# I have two independently working functions - I cannot get them to work together

Tags: javascript

I have two independent functions one to build a carousel and one to detect swipe Left or Right.

I cannot seem to find a way to use the function which navigates through the carousel into my Swipe Left or Right function (or vice versa).

I am at the end of my JS coding limits and struggling.

Here is the except:

```
  this.doSomething = (event) => {
    if (this.whatGestureDirection() == 'L') {
      hpCarousel.move(-1);
    } else {
      hpCarousel.move(1);
    }
  }
```

I have tried alternatives; having google'd around there is a bind method. However, this is a bust too.

```
  this.doSomething = (event) => {
    if (this.whatGestureDirection() == 'L') {
      let bindTheFunc;
      bindTheFunc.bind(hpCarousel.move(-1));
      return bindTheFunc;
    } else {
      let bindTheFunc;
      bindTheFunc.bind(hpCarousel.move(1));
      return bindTheFunc;
    }
  }
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const hpCarousel = new carousel('area', 1);
  const hpCarouselSwipe = new getSwipeX({elementId: 'homepage_carousel_wrapper'});
})
function getSwipeX({elementId}) {
  this.e               = document.getElementsByClassName(elementId)[0];
  this.initialPosition = 0;
  this.lastPosition    = 0;
  this.getTouchStart = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (window.PointerEvent) {
      this.e.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
    }
    return this.initalTouchPos = this.getGesturePoint(event);
  }
  this.getTouchMove  = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return this.lastPosition = this.getGesturePoint(event);
  }
  this.getTouchEnd   = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (window.PointerEvent) {
      this.e.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
    }
    this.doSomething();
    this.initialPosition = 0;
  }
  this.getGesturePoint = (event) => {
    this.point = event.pageX
    return this.point;
  }
  this.whatGestureDirection = (event) => {
    const diffInPosition  = this.initalTouchPos - this.lastPosition;
    return (Math.sign(diffInPosition) > 0 ) ? `L` : `R`;
  }
  this.doSomething = (event) => {
    if (this.whatGestureDirection() == 'L') {
      **hpCarousel.move(-1);**
    } else {
      **hpCarousel.move(1);**
    }
  }
  if (window.PointerEvent) {
    this.e.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.getTouchStart, true);
    this.e.addEventListener('pointermove', this.getTouchMove, true);
    this.e.addEventListener('pointerup', this.getTouchEnd, true);
    this.e.addEventListener('pointercancel', this.getTouchEnd, true);
  }
}
```

I have a carousel script which a SO user kindly helped me with last week. It works great.

```
function carousel(id, index) {

  this.slideIndex = index;
  let carousel = document.getElementById(id);
  this.slides = [...document.getElementsByClassName('homepage_carousel')];

  let prev = carousel.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0];
  let next = carousel.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];
  
  prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(-1);
  });

  next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.move(1);
  });

  this.hideAll = () => {
    this.slides.forEach((slide) => {
      slide.style.display = 'none';
    });
  };

  this.show = () => {
    this.hideAll();
    this.slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'flex';
  }

  this.move = (amount) => {
    this.slideIndex += amount;
    this.slideIndex = (this.slideIndex > this.slides.length) ? 1 : (this.slideIndex < 1) ? this.slides.length : this.slideIndex;
    this.show();
  }

  this.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass `hpCarousel` into `hpCarouselSwipe` as an argument.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const hpCarousel = new carousel('area', 1);
  const hpCarouselSwipe = new getSwipeX({elementId: 'homepage_carousel_wrapper', carousel:hpCarousel});
})
function getSwipeX({elementId,carousel}) {
    ... 
    this.hpCarousel = carousel
}
```

And then later:

```
this.doSomething = (event) => {
    if (this.whatGestureDirection() == 'L') {
      this.hpCarousel.move(-1);
    } else {
      this.hpCarousel.move(1);
    }
  }
```

I did not test it, but it should work. You can pass a function into another function.

Comment: My mind has exploded - thank you for your guidance; your suggestions worked the first time.

Comment: The reason it didn't work in your code is, that you declared `hpCarousel` inside the onload function. So it is in that function scope. Therefore `getSwipeX` doesn't know about it. (just a side node, for explaination) , glad I could help :-)